# Ambiguidade em pronomes: "ataquem-nos" pode ser "os ataquem" e "nos ataquem"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu, pronomes, ambiguidades

A oração com pronome oblíquo átono **"o ataquem"** pode virar **"ataquem-no"** quando em ênclise.

Logo, a oração com pronome oblíquo átono **"os ataquem"** pode virar  **"ataquem-nos"** quando em ênclise.

Mas, a oração com pronome oblíquo átono **"nos ataquem"** pode virar **"ataquem-nos"** quando em ênclise.

Fiz algo errado? Por que são iguais? Há forma de diferenciá-los?

Comment: Adreas, vê se gostas do novo título. Se não gostares, clica "edit" à esquerda abaixo da pergunta, e muda à tua vontade; a pergunta é tua. A minha ideia foi tornar o título mais explícito. E parece-me que a tua dúvida não é sobre a colocação do pronome (estava "colocação pronominal" no original), mas sobre a ambiguidade de "-nos" em certos casos. Como as respostas abaixo dizem, é mesmo "-nos" nos teu dois casos. Se houver ambiguidade, desambiguamos. Por exemplo, "Eles, no conflito entre nós e os vizinhos, apoiam-nos"; como fica ambíguo, esclarece--"apoiam-nos a nós" ou "apoiam-nos a eles".

Answer (score 4):

Eu sou de Portugal e o pronome só se usa antes do verbo quando a frase se encontra na negativa. Distinguir o "-nos" só pode ser feito dependendo do contexto da frase:

Ex.:

Se vocês **nos** acham fracos, ataquem-nos. (que nos ataquem)

Se vocês **os** acham fracos, ataquem-nos (a eles)

Answer (score 4):

Sim, é verdade, são iguais, mas é muito raro isso causar alguma ambiguidade, pelo menos comparado com outros casos como quando a 1ª e a 3ª pessoas do singular são iguais (no Imperfeito do Indicativo ou em *(eu/ele) disse*, por exemplo).

No caso que indicas, parte da razão é que *ataquem* é geralmente uma forma do conjuntivo, e portanto aparece geralmente em orações subordinadas, que forçam sempre a próclise. Portanto, exceptuando casos como *ataquem-nos ou não (= quer nos/os ataquem, quer não)*, a possibilidade de haver ambiguidade surgirá quase sempre apenas quando se trata do imperativo.